# Proving the following matrix equality where $\sigma_{min}(A) > 1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing

For an $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ such that $\sigma_{min}(A) > 1$, we can form an invertible $A^TA-I$ and $AA^T-I$. Note that $\sigma_{min}(A)$ is the smallest singular value of $A$. I am trying to show:

> $$A(A^TA-I)^{-1}A^T - I = (AA^T-I)^{-1}$$

I feel like there's some clever trick to showing this almost immediately, but I can't quite find it myself. By the following expansion,

$$\begin{aligned}
A(A^TA-I)^{-1}A^T - I &= A(A^TA-I)^{-1}A^T - (AA^T-I)(AA^T-I)^{-1} \\
&= A(A^TA-I)^{-1}A^T - AA^T(AA^T-I)^{-1} + (AA^T-I)^{-1}
\end{aligned}$$

we have that the original problem is equivalent to showing:

> $$A(A^TA-I)^{-1}A^T = AA^T(AA^T-I)^{-1}$$

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to prove this either. Thanks for any help or ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $B=AA^T-I$. Then it is easy to show that $BA=A(A^TA-I)$, hence

$$B(A(A^TA-I)^{-1}A^T - I)=I.$$

Comment: Thanks for that. Noticing that my right hand side is an inverse should be a big flag to me that I should be able to multiply both sides by the inverse and get the identity!